# Why is pressing "Enter" equivalent to the number 0?

Tags: powershell

I don't understand why pressing enter key is the same as pressing 0 on the keyboard.

```
[int] $Choice = -1
$Count = 2

while ($Choice -lt 0 -or $Choice -gt $Count)
{
    Write-Host "Input number"
    $Choice = Read-Host

    Write-Host "choice:"
    Write-Host $Choice

}
```

The output will be 0 even if just press enter. I want the user to explicitly input 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the very first statement:

```
[int] $Choice = -1
```

... you type-cast `$choice` to `[int]`.

When you apply a cast to the *left*-hand side of an assignment (to the left of the variable name), PowerShell will "remember" it as a type-constraint and treat the variable as strongly typed - PowerShell will attempt to convert anything you assign to `$choice` from there on out to an `[int]`.

Hitting enter in the prompt without any other input results in `Read-Host` returning an empty string (like `""`)

The conversion logic treats the empty string as `$null`, and casting `$null` to `[int]` results in the value `0`. You can see this by casting an empty string to `[int]` directly:

```
PS C:\> [int]""
0
```

You should probably validate the input from `Read-Host` before assigning to `$Choice` if you explicitly require a number:

```
$inputString = Read-Host
if($inputString -notmatch '^\d+$') {
    Write-Host "Digits only please!"
    continue
}
```

Comment: I see thank you!, however your regex will also be `$true ` for negative numbers, here is what works `-notmatch '^-?\d+$'`

Comment: @metablaster that's deliberate, you use `0` as a lower bound in your loop condition, why would you accept negative numbers from `Read-Host`?

Comment: Yes indeed, to avoid the "Digits only please!" message which should not be displayed for negative numbers just like it's not displayed for too big numbers. since this `if` is only to check digits, unlike `while` which checks the range.